# Proving interchangeability of limit and integral for $\lim_{k\to0}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x^2+1)}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

As the title asks, I would like to ask if $\lim_{k\to0}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x^2+1)}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\infty}\lim_{k\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x^2+1)}\mathrm{d}x$. I'm sure there's some form of convergence theorem that I have to use, and highly likely that it's the DCT, but I can't think of the sequence of functions I should use. Could someone guide me on this please? Thanks!

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty}\lim_{k\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x^2+1)}\mathrm{d}x$ does not exist as  a Lebesgue intergal. So DCT cannot be used. This question involves improper Riemann integrals.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x(k^2x^2+1)}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-\frac{k^2x\sin(x)}{k^2x^2+1}\right)\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{x\mapsto x/k}\frac\pi2 -\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(x/k)}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{IBP}}\frac\pi2 +k\underbrace{\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\cos(x/k)\right)\,dx}_{\text{Absolutely Convergent}}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: (+) seems so easy!

Comment: Are you not missing a $k$ in the numerator, after $x\mapsto x/k$? And what do you mean by IBP?

Comment: @Cornman: All seems to be fine: $$-\int^\infty_0\frac{x}{1+x^2}\sin(x/k)\,dx =k\int^\infty_0 \frac{x}{1+x^2}d(\cos(x/k)$$

Comment: @cornman IBP is integration by parts

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @oliverdiaz Thank you my friend.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @user107224 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I  really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f: [0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with

$$f(x,k) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)} , & x \neq 0 \\0, & x = 0\end{cases}$$

is continuous. For any $R> 0$, it follows that $F(k) = \int _0^Rf(x,k) \, dx$ is continuous and

$$\tag{1}\lim_{k \to 0} \int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx = \int_0^R \frac{\sin x }{x} \, dx$$

(Swapping the limit and the integral of a continuous function over a finite interval is permitted)

Note that

$$\left|\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx - \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx   \right| = \left|\int_R^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx + \int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx - \int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx -  \int_R^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx \right|\\ \leqslant \left| \int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx - \int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx \right|+\left|\int_R^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx\right| + \left|  \int_R^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx\right|$$

Since the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx$ is convergent, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $R_1>0$ such that $ \left|  \int_R^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for all $R > R_1$.

We also have, by the Dirichlet test for improper integrals, uniform convergence of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx$ and there exists $R_2 > 0$ such that $\left|\int_R^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for all $R > R_2$ and all $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hence, choosing any $R > \max(R_1,R_2)$ we have

$$\tag{2}\left|\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx - \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx   \right| \leqslant  \left| \int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx - \int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx \right|+ \frac{2\epsilon}{3}$$

By (1) it follows that there exists $\delta > 0$ (which may depend on $R$ without consequence) such that if $|k-0| < \delta$, then

$$\tag{3} \left|\int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx - \int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx   \right| \leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{3},$$

and together with $(2)$ this implies

$$\left|\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx - \int_0^R\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx   \right| \leqslant \epsilon$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{k \to 0} \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x+1)}\, dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x }{x} \, dx$$

Comment: Hi my friend.  We fix $R$.  Then, we choose a $\delta>0$.  So, yes our choice of $\delta$ does depend on what fixed $R$ we have chosen.  And you are correct that this is inconsequential.